# Trying to Customize OrderBy with IQueryable - "Skip" method error

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, skip

The first part of my code gets the IQueryable data results:

```
var issues = repository.GetAllIssues().Where(i => 
                  i.IssueNotificationRecipients.Any(r => r.Status == "Open"));
```

Then I determine which sort order the user has requested, and add it:

```
switch (sort)
{
case 1:
    issues.OrderBy(x => x.Customer);
    break;
case 2:
    issues.OrderBy(x => x.Description);
    break;
case 3:
    issues.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedBy);
    break;
default:
    issues.OrderBy(x => x.DueDateTime);
    break;
}
```

This throws the error:

> The method 'Skip' is only supported
>   for sorted input in LINQ to Entities.
>   The method 'OrderBy' must be called
>   before the method 'Skip'

So how can I add the OrderBy dynamically, in response to my user's input?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown us all of your code, but one problem is that you're expecting `issues.OrderBy(..)` to *mutate* the queryable referred to by the `issues` variable. But it doesn't actually do that; it *returns* a new `IOrderedQueryable` that represents an ordered version of the original queryable.

Since your ordering operations aren't actually touching the queryable referred to be your `issues` variable; it makes sense that calling `Skip` on it results in the error that you're getting, because it *hasn't* actually been sorted.

You probably want to do:

```
issues = issues.OrderBy(...);
```

Comment: This answer was a life saver! Most of my entities I call ToList in my service classes because I return small numbers of records.  I started using IQueryable to return larger sets and I couldn't figure out why OrderBy was not working.  Using a different variable returns IOrderedQueryable which fixed everything.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you perhaps mean

```
switch (sort)
{
case 1:
    issues = issues.OrderBy(x => x.Customer);
    break;
case 2:
    issues = issues.OrderBy(x => x.Description);
    break;
case 3:
    issues = issues.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedBy);
    break;
default:
    issues = issues.OrderBy(x => x.DueDateTime);
    break;
}
```

You may need to change the type of `issues`, or set it to a new variable, since it returns `IOrderedQueryable<T>`